# Company wants me to be silent about doing Freelance outside work

Tags: freelancing

I work full time in a company and started doing some extras as a freelancer.
It was not initially authorized by my company and had to negotiate a modification on the contract.
They asked me to be silent about it and not share it with other colleagues.

I got my first contracts by putting ads on freelance website but I'd like to share with my LinkedIn network too, e.g by putting a status offering my services. If I do, colleagues will know and this can harm me potentially more.

The question is: how can I profit of my LinkedIn network without harming my relationship with my company.

Comment: If you don't want to publish this on Linkedin, you probably don't want to publish it here either. Your profile contains your name and your employeer's name.

Comment: Your question seems to be asking for the impossible - you can't post ads on your LinkedIn profile without risking having your colleagues see it. Although that's not to say you can't post on other sites, or reach out to people instead of waiting for them to reach out to you.

Comment: Your point is valid, but they'd have to explicitly google me to find this topic. I am taking the risk as it is very unlikely someone will do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I wouldn't risk putting it as a status** because, as you said, your colleagues will know.  In this instance I don't think there is a way to use LinkedIn without negative side effects.  Consider instead directly messaging people that might be interested in your services, or simply not using LinkedIn at all and continuing to use freelance websites.

If you want more information about freelancing, check out the [Freelancing SE.](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/)  You might be able to find more information about getting exposure there.  For example, here is a question on [how to get your first job at a freelancing site.](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site)